# The requested list key 'userRegisterTO.countryList' could not be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I was working with Struts 2.0 , Hibernate and JPA . But i got this strage error on my jsp page so please help me if you have any solution for the above problem please find the action class detail. In action class i am getting the value of `userRegisterTO` object and complete `countryList` but on jsp `userRegisterTO` can not be resolved . So please help what am i doing wrong.

Action class

```
public class UserRegistrationAction extends ActionSupport {
    private UserRegisterInterface userRegisterInterface = new UserRegisterService();
    public UserRegisterTO userRegisterTO = null;
    public String registerUser() {
        userRegisterTO = new UserRegisterTO(); 
        this.userRegisterTO = this.userRegisterInterface.listCountryName();
        System.out.println("The size of the list is -  ------ = "+userRegisterTO.getCountryList().size());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Note - in SOP i getting the size of the list but on jsp userRegisterTO can not be resolved

JSP

```
<s:form action="/admin/test">
    <s:textfield label="Please enter your name" name="name"/>
    <s:submit/>
    <s:select list="userRegisterTO.countryList" 
        listkey="id" 
        listvalue="countryName"/>
</s:form>
```

UserRegisterTO

```
public class UserRegisterTO 
{ 
  public List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>(); 
  public List<Country> getCountryList() 
  { 
   return countryList; 
   } 
  public void setCountryList(List<Country> countryList) { 
    this.countryList = countryList;
   }
```

---

My action class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.castle.user.register.action;
import com.castle.user.register.service.UserRegisterInterface;
import com.castle.user.register.service.UserRegisterService;
import com.castle.user.register.service.UserRegisterTO;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

/**
 * @author Rahul
 *
 */
public class UserRegistrationAction extends ActionSupport {

    private UserRegisterInterface userRegisterInterface = new UserRegisterService();
    private UserRegisterTO userRegisterTO = null;
    public String registerUser(){
         //userRegisterTO = new UserRegisterTO(); 
        this.userRegisterTO = this.userRegisterInterface.listCountryName();
        System.out.println("The size of the list is -  ------ = "+userRegisterTO.getCountryList().size());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public UserRegisterTO getUserRegisterTO() {
        return userRegisterTO;
    }
    public void setUserRegisterTO(UserRegisterTO userRegisterTO) {
        this.userRegisterTO = userRegisterTO;
    }


}
```

My service class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.castle.user.register.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.castle.model.Country;
import com.castle.user.dao.UserRegisterDAO;
import com.castle.user.dao.UserRegisterDAOInterface;

/**
 * @author Rahul
 *
 */
public class UserRegisterService implements UserRegisterInterface{

    private UserRegisterDAOInterface userRegisterDAOInterface = new UserRegisterDAO();

    @Override
    public UserRegisterTO listCountryName() {
        List<Country> countryList = null;
        UserRegisterTO userRegisterTO = new UserRegisterTO();
        try{
            countryList = this.userRegisterDAOInterface.countryList();
            userRegisterTO.setCountryList(countryList);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userRegisterTO;
    }

}
```

My dao class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.castle.user.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.castle.model.Country;

/**
 * @author Rahul
 *
 */
public class UserRegisterDAO implements UserRegisterDAOInterface {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public UserRegisterDAO() {
        this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("blogds");
        this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Country> countryList() {
        List<Country> countryList = null;
        String query =null;
        Query q =null;
        try{
            query = "select c from com.castle.model.Country c";
            countryList = (List<Country>)entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return countryList;
    }

}
```

action.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="user" namespace="/user/registration" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="registerUser" class="com.castle.user.register.action.UserRegistrationAction" method="registerUser">
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/jsp/register/register.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

</struts>
```

my jsp -

```
<%@include file="/header.jsp"%>
<s:form action="/admin/test">
    <s:textfield label="Please enter your name" name="name"/>
    <s:submit/>
    <s:select list="userRegisterTO.countryList" 
        listkey="id" 
        listvalue="countryName"></s:select>

</s:form>
<%@include file="/footer.jsp"%>
```

still the problem is same please provide and work around

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a public getter method for most (all?) versions of Struts 2.0; the ability to access public properties happened later.

Direct member access is not recommended.

---

*Edit for new code posted*

How do you reach the `input.jsp` page, the page with the form?

I don't see any code that sets `userRegisterTO` for the `input` result, which is where it appears you're seeing the error.

You might consider using the [`prepare` interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/prepare-interceptor.html) and the [`Preparable` interface](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html) to initialize the `userRegisterTO`.

Comment: all the getter method are public please see following model
public class UserRegisterTO {

 public List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

 public List<Country> getCountryList() {
  return countryList;
 }

 public void setCountryList(List<Country> countryList) {
  this.countryList = countryList;
 }



still the problem is same.......

Comment: @RahulWagh Yeah, I can't read that--put it in the question. I'm talking about the getter for the TO in the action, not the country list. If that doesn't fix it, you'll need to provide the action configuration(s) you're using to get to the JSP, and verify that all paths to the JSP set the TO correctly, for example, after a validation error.

Comment: Hi dave please if u can look at my code which i have posted and provide me any solution thanks

Comment: @RahulWagh Please post additional information as part of the question, not as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulWagh See updated answer. Nutshell: I don't see how `userRegisterTO` is initialized when you go to the `input` result.

Comment: Please see my configuration 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
<action name="registerUser" class="com.castle.user.register.action.UserRegistrationAction" method="registerUser">
  <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
  <result name="success" type="redirect">/jsp/register/register.jsp</result>
 </action>
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @RahulWagh Yeah, I can't read that. Put it in your question. Although it seems to just be your action configuration again, which doesn't answer the question. You return `"success"` from `registerUser`, which means that isn't how you get to `input.jsp`. Question still stands--how to you **initially** get to `input.jsp`, and how do you initialize `userRegisterTO` when you do??? And *which* JSP are you showing in your question???

Comment: i do have submit button on the index.jsp page configured in web.xml as landing page. On click of submit button the registerUser action is called which return success and goes to register.jsp

Comment: @RahulWagh HOW DO YOU GET TO `index.jsp`??? WHAT SETS `userRegisterTO` WHEN THAT HAPPENS?

Answer (score 0):

What you have provided is `getter and setter` on your `model/domain` class.When action will done its work and will send back the result to your UI Struts2 will place the action and any of its properties defined inside the Action class in the `values-stack`.

So on your JSP when you will try to access the properties using OGNL, framework will try to resolve them against properties in the `Value-Stack`.

So this entry `userRegisterTO.countryList` will work like

```
getUseruserRegisterTO().getCountryList();
```

In Short Framework will look for a method `getUseruserRegisterTO()` in your Action class and than will call `getCountryList()` if resolution will work.

As per your action class we are not able to see any getter method for `userRegisterTO`, so i believe that your action should be like

```
public class UserRegistrationAction extends ActionSupport {
  private UserRegisterInterface userRegisterInterface = new UserRegisterService();
  public UserRegisterTO userRegisterTO = null;
  public String registerUser() {
            userRegisterTO = new UserRegisterTO(); 
            this.userRegisterTO = this.userRegisterInterface.listCountryName();
            return SUCCESS;
        }

public UserRegisterTO  getUserRegisterTO(){
    return this.userRegisterTO ;
} 

//setter for userRegisterTO
```

if it still not working for you provide your `configuration file(s)`.

Comment: Hi umesh ,
Please see below i have posted all my action, service , dao, action.xml and jsp file please suggest problem is still same

Comment: I tried that but it is not working please see below my action.xml file
    <package name="user" namespace="/user/registration" extends="struts-default">
     <action name="registerUser" class="com.castle.user.register.action.UserRegistrationAction" method="registerUser">
      <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
      <result name="success" type="redirect">/jsp/register/register.jsp</result>
     </action>
    </package>

Comment: @RahulWagh: i am not very sure about what you are doing but need more inputs to suggest any solution 1.) which jsp you are getting error for `success` or `input` mappped?

Comment: for success i am getting this error while in action class i am getting the complete list and return success is executed properly.

Comment: @RahulWagh if i see it right you are redirecting your action using `redirect` result type that means a new request is being created and fresh action values will be placed in the valuestack,so you have to save your `userRegisterTO`.For checking just edit your struts.xml as  `<action name="registerUser" class="com.castle.user.register.action.UserRegistrationAction" method="registerUser">
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/register/register.jsp</result>
    </action>
` and let us know the outcome